# Widget area does not show any contents for specific users in admin interface. How to go about debugging?

Tags: widgets

I use a custom theme on a WP-Multisite instance which also uses WPML plugin. I am pretty technical  and I can read PHP code but I do not have any WP experience.

The theme has three custom widget areas - footer left, footer center and footer right.

As a network admin I can properly put content in all the widget areas. But users, who are admins on only the actual sites they want to edit can only edit the content in the center and right content area.

When trying to edit the content in the left footer area as site admin without network admin permissions, however, the content does not show up.

What's worse, when I edit the content in the center or right footer area as as a site-admin, then the content in the left (which I can't see) gets deleted.

Any idea how to go about this issue? I can't really disable any of the plugins as this is a production system. Should I satrt building a staging system, or does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Comment: In WordPress installation root find `wp-config.php` file and at the bottom of the page fine `define('WP-DEBUG', false);`, just make it "`true`". This is WordPress's default Debugging method.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Thanks for your tip. This would however make debug information available to ordinary users on the HTML pages themselves. Is this correct?

Comment: I would definitely advise to put together separate dev install (usually local). Debug in production is more challenging and risky. There isn't enough here without actual code and debug to make a good guess.